# Async wait for function to be done

Tags: javascript

I'm strugeling with async/await order, I need the code to wait for the getAttachements and proceed after but thats not working atm. I have looked at some options on SE for example a callback function but i did not get it to work yet.

```
processJsonToXML()

async function processJsonToXML() {
    for (let i = 0; i < wordpressOutput.length; i++) {
        imageUrls = []
        let obj = wordpressOutput[i];
        let content = processContent(obj.Content)

        await getAttachments().then(attachments =>{
            const filledXml = xmlTemplate(
                {
                    title: obj.Title, 
                    content: content, 
                    date: obj.Date, 
                    summary: obj.Excerpt, 
                    unixTime: moment(obj.Date).unix(),
                    attachments: attachments
                }
            )
    
            fs.writeFile(`xml-files/${obj.Title}.xml`, filledXml, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('File is created successfully.');
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Second part is the code to fetch an url and create a object out of it with the info I need in the first function.

```
async function getAttachments(){
const attachments: attachment[] = []

imageUrls.forEach(async url  => {
    let filename = extractUsingRegex(url, /([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-\(\):])+(.png|.jpg)/gm);
    await fetch(url).then(response => {
        response.buffer().then(resolvedBuffer => {
            let attachment: attachment = {
                type: response.type,
                content: resolvedBuffer.toString('base64'),
                filename: filename,
                size: response.size.toString()
            }   
            console.log(attachment);
            

            attachments.push(attachment)
        })
    });
})

return attachments
}
```

Comment: Are you using `fs/promises`? If not, you should be

Comment: 1. Don't use `await fetch(...).then(...)` 2. to run multiple promises at the same time, use Promise.all() 3. return the a promise from a normal function, then `await` it elsewhere

Comment: Here's a fixed version of the second snippet: https://pastebin.com/9sk0DRj2

Comment: @ChrisG thanks its working perfectly now, I'm reading up on promises more to fully understand whats going on things are not as clear as I thought yet

Comment: Great, note that you appear to be loading the same attachments multiple times; do they have to be inside the for loop? Also, `imageUrls` appears to be empty when getAttachments() runs, which means it doesn't really do anything?

Answer (score -1):

Your first part of the code should look like this

```
processJsonToXML();
async function processJsonToXML() {
await Promise.all(
    wordpressOutput.map(async (obj) => {
    imageUrls = [];
    let content = processContent(obj.Content);

    let attachments = await getAttachments();
    const filledXml = xmlTemplate({
      title: obj.Title,
      content: content,
      date: obj.Date,
      summary: obj.Excerpt,
      unixTime: moment(obj.Date).unix(),
      attachments: attachments,
    });
  fs.writeFile(`xml-files/${obj.Title}.xml`, filledXml, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("File is created successfully.");
  });
}) );}
```

And Second part of your code should look like this

```
async function getAttachments(){
const attachments: attachment[] = []
await Promise.all(
imageUrls.map(async url  => {
    let filename = extractUsingRegex(url, /([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-\(\):])+(.png|.jpg)/gm);
    await fetch(url).then(response => {
        response.buffer().then(resolvedBuffer => {
            let attachment: attachment = {
                type: response.type,
                content: resolvedBuffer.toString('base64'),
                filename: filename,
                size: response.size.toString()
            }   
            console.log(attachment);
            

            attachments.push(attachment)
        })
    });
}));
return attachments
}
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Yes and not, it works better then before but for  some reason its not waiting for all attachments but only one. So when the first atttachment is loaded it will generate 2 files and the other attachements from both files come in later